# How to assign in one step the values of an array to the corresponding row of a Window in Pyspark?

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark

I'm trying to apply a [Savgol filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) to smooth a time series. I have a set of time series in the same dataframe that can be identified with an id. Thus, I want to apply the Savgol filter independently to each of the time series (each of the ids). For doing so, I have created the next window

```
window_spec = Window.partitionBy(F.col("id")).orderBy(F.col("timestamp"))
```

Then, I can apply an UDF to this window with the Scipy function ([savgol_filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html)). However, the problem of this function is that it takes a whole array as input and returns the "smoothed" array. For example:

```
time_series = [4,3,5,5,6,5,4,3,3]  # len(time_series) = 9
savgol_filter(time_series, window_length = 3, polyorder = 1)  # This returns an array of length 9 in which the first position corresponds to the smoothed value of the first position of time_series, and so on
```

I can collect a list with the ordered values of the window, apply this function to the whole list and then take the corresponding index. However, this is very inefficient. This function (`savgol_filter`) returns an array that has to be 'copied' in the rows of the window one-by-one. For example, if the window is of size 5, the value in the first position of the returned array by `savgol_filter` should be copied in the row that corresponds with the first position of the window, and so on. Is there a way to do this without calculating `savgol_filter` once for each row, but only once for each window, and then assign the values to the corresponding row?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [groupBy("id")](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html) together with [applyInPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html) instead of a window:

```python
#create some test data
data = [
      [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [1, 5, 6], [1, 6, 5],
      [1, 7, 4], [1, 8, 3], [1, 9, 3], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 5],
      [2, 4, 6], [2, 5, 9], [2, 6, 2], [3, 1, 7], [3, 2, 6], [3, 3, 5],
      [3, 4, 4], [3, 5, 4], [3, 6, 2]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema = ["id", "timestamp", "value"])

from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

def apply_savgol_filter(pandas_df):
      pandas_df.sort_values("timestamp", inplace=True)
      pandas_df["updated_value"] = \
            savgol_filter(pandas_df["value"], window_length = 3, polyorder = 1)
      return pandas_df

df.groupBy("id").applyInPandas(apply_savgol_filter, 
      'id:bigint,timestamp:bigint,value:bigint,updated_value:bigint').show(5)
```

Output:

```
+---+---------+-----+-------------+
| id|timestamp|value|updated_value|
+---+---------+-----+-------------+
|  1|        1|    4|            3|
|  1|        2|    3|            4|
|  1|        3|    5|            4|
|  1|        4|    5|            5|
|  1|        5|    6|            5|
+---+---------+-----+-------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```